# Correct way to use onClickListener with MediaPlayer parameters and an array

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i started learning few days ago, and im trying to get this buttons to work, its just a grid of buttons that should play a different sound each one, but it crashes when i try to play any, almost all my code is from this link http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/ and the onClick code is this one, but it doesnt work.

---

```
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Preform a function based on the position

            if(mp!=null){
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();}
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(filenames[this.position]);
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, uri);
            mp.start();
```

---

And this is the error i get in the logcat

```
    03-08 06:38:31.789  11339-11349/com.ntugta.hellogridview E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
    03-08 06:38:31.805  11339-11339/com.ntugta.hellogridview D/MediaPlayer﹕ create failed:
    java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:812)
```

Forgot to add, the array for the played files is like this.

```
public String[] filesnames = { 
        "R.raw.file1", 
        "R.raw.file2",
        "R.raw.file3"
        };
```

**EDIT:**
had to change name files to this with that way of playing.

```
public String[] filesnames = { 
        "file1", 
        "file2",
        "file3"
        };
```

**EDIT:**

I found how to do it, first problem was bad state on the if, it was .reset(); what i should run, and not .stop() and .release(), the second mistake was that Uri, it should have been a resource identifier based on the string i got from the array, and this is the final code.

```
String data = filenames[this.position];
if (m != null) {
m.reset();
}
m = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,getResources().getIdentifier(data, "raw", "com.example.package"));
m.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create failed, so it returned null.  You didn't check for this, so when you call mp.start you crash.  First off, you should check for mp.create returning null and not call start if it does.  Secondly, you can't do strings like that.  R.raw.xxx is NOT a filename.  Its a resource id, that refers to a resource you can open via openResource.  You need to put the data somewhere you can get a FileDescriptor, like the assets directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was a better way to do it with assets folder, but a long way for me, tried but couldnt make it work, so i came back to the create() with a dynamic way, which is not the best for the kind of app im trying to do, but i learned a lot, the fix is on the OP. Good luck!